# FTP and execute shell scripts on windows from linux

Tags: linux, windows, shell, ssh, ftp

I'm trying to run automatic tests using Jenkins and I want to execute commands from my Jenkins server, which is a Lenny-64 on another virtual machine with Win7. To be clear, if I wanted to do it via two Unix machines, I would have done it using this:

```
ssh -i private_key python /root/test.py
```

Now, what is the alternative command for a windows target machine, or what should I deploy to run this on a windows machine.

Plus I want to transfer files from/to Jenkins server to/from Win7 machine.

How can I do these tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working around and I solved the issue. I installed `cygwin` with `openssl` and `openssh` libraries. For connections, I used RSA keys and for `websvn` commands, I used Tortoise SVN tool along with its command line.